# Javascript sort works in Firefox not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Javascript sort works in Firefox but not Chrome. Just a simple Select that takes a user to a new url. What modifications can I make to make it work on all browsers?

Stackoverflow says I need more explanation text. Although I thought it was a fairly straightforward question. A user selects an option and is directed to a new url. The code redirects in Firefox but it does not redirect in Chrome. I have not checked other browsers.

```js
function url() {
  var value1 = $("#sort").val();
  var currentURL = window.location.href;

  if (window.location.href.endsWith("/")) {
    var str1 = (currentURL + '?');
  } else if (window.location.href.includes('&orderby')) {
    var str1 = (currentURL.split('&orderby')[0] + '&');

  } else if (window.location.href.includes('?orderby')) {
    var str1 = (currentURL.split('?orderby')[0] + '?');

  } else {
    var str1 = (currentURL + '&');
  }


  if (value1 == 'sort1') {
    window.location.href = str1 + "orderby=date&order=dsc";
  }
  if (value1 == 'sort3') {
    window.location.href = str1 + "orderby=date&order=asc";
  }
  if (value1 == 'sort5') {
    window.location.href = str1 + "orderby=title&order=dsc";
  }
  if (value1 == 'sort7') {
    window.location.href = str1 + "orderby=title&order=asc";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sort" class="sorts2">
  <option class="sorts-option" value="">Sort</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort1" onclick="url()">Latest</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort3" onclick="url()">Oldest</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort5" onclick="url()">Title DSC</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort7" onclick="url()">Title ASC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do `onchange` on select rather than `onclick` on option tags. (As select is the actual input control and you have to bind event to `select` tag only.

Like this

```js
function url() {
  var value1 = $("#sort").val();
  var currentURL = window.location.href;

  if (window.location.href.endsWith("/")) {
    var str1 = (currentURL + '?');
  } else if (window.location.href.includes('&orderby')) {
    var str1 = (currentURL.split('&orderby')[0] + '&');

  } else if (window.location.href.includes('?orderby')) {
    var str1 = (currentURL.split('?orderby')[0] + '?');

  } else {
    var str1 = (currentURL + '&');
  }


  if (value1 == 'sort1') {
    window.location.href = str1 + "orderby=date&order=dsc";
  }
  if (value1 == 'sort3') {
    window.location.href = str1 + "orderby=date&order=asc";
  }
  if (value1 == 'sort5') {
    window.location.href = str1 + "orderby=title&order=dsc";
  }
  if (value1 == 'sort7') {
    window.location.href = str1 + "orderby=title&order=asc";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sort" class="sorts2" onchange="url()">
  <option class="sorts-option" value="">Sort</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort1" >Latest</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort3" >Oldest</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort5" >Title DSC</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort7" >Title ASC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting an `<option>` will not trigger a `click` event in Chrome. Try listening for a `change` event on the `<select>` instead:

```js
$('#sort').on('change', url);

function url(e) {
  console.log('url running');
  var value1 = $("#sort").val();
  var currentURL = window.location.href;

  if (window.location.href.endsWith("/")) {
    var str1 = (currentURL + '?');
  } else if (window.location.href.includes('&orderby')) {
    var str1 = (currentURL.split('&orderby')[0] + '&');

  } else if (window.location.href.includes('?orderby')) {
    var str1 = (currentURL.split('?orderby')[0] + '?');

  } else {
    var str1 = (currentURL + '&');
  }

  console.log('insert code to assign to window.location.href here...');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sort" class="sorts2">
  <option class="sorts-option" value="">Sort</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort1">Latest</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort3">Oldest</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort5">Title DSC</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort7">Title ASC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: onChange="url() is the correct solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using jQuery it is better use [jQuery.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

```js
$('#sort').change(function () {
  var value1 = this.value;
  var currentURL = window.location.href;

  if (window.location.href.endsWith('/')) {
    var str1 = (currentURL + '?');
  } else if (window.location.href.includes('&orderby')) {
    var str1 = (currentURL.split('&orderby')[0] + '&');
  } else if (window.location.href.includes('?orderby')) {
    var str1 = (currentURL.split('?orderby')[0] + '?');
  } else {
    var str1 = (currentURL + '&');
  }

  if (value1 == 'sort1') {
    str1 += 'orderby=date&order=dsc';
  }
  if (value1 == 'sort3') {
    str1 += 'orderby=date&order=asc';
  }
  if (value1 == 'sort5') {
    str1 += 'orderby=title&order=dsc';
  }
  if (value1 == 'sort7') {
    str1 += 'orderby=title&order=asc';
  }
  
  console.log(str1);
  // window.location.href = str1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sort" class="sorts2">
  <option class="sorts-option" value="">Sort</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort1">Latest</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort3">Oldest</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort5">Title DSC</option>
  <option class="sorts-option" value="sort7">Title ASC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding "Onclick" event to every option, use the "OnChange" event for select. then it will work automatically.
       `<select id="sort" class="sorts2" onChange="url()">
          <option class="sorts-option" value="">Sort</option>
          <option class="sorts-option" value="sort1" >Latest</option>
          <option class="sorts-option" value="sort3" >Oldest</option>
          <option class="sorts-option" value="sort5" >Title DSC</option>
          <option class="sorts-option" value="sort7" >Title ASC</option>
        </select>`

try this.